# Slices in golang do not allocate any memory?

Tags: pointers, go, slice

This link: http://research.swtch.com/godata

It says (third paragraph of section Slices):

> Because slices are multiword structures, not pointers, the slicing
>   operation does not need to allocate memory, not even for the slice
>   header, which can usually be kept on the stack. This representation
>   makes slices about as cheap to use as passing around explicit pointer
>   and length pairs in C. Go originally represented a slice as a pointer
>   to the structure shown above, but doing so meant that every slice
>   operation allocated a new memory object. Even with a fast allocator,
>   that creates a lot of unnecessary work for the garbage collector, and
>   we found that, as was the case with strings above, programs avoided
>   slicing operations in favor of passing explicit indices. Removing the
>   indirection and the allocation made slices cheap enough to avoid
>   passing explicit indices in most cases.

What...? Why does it not allocate any memory? If it is a multiword structure or a pointer? Does it not need to allocate memory? Then it mentions that it was originally a pointer to that slice structure, and it needed to allocate memory for a new object. Why does it not need to do that now? Very confused

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on [Pravin Mishra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29196849/55504):

> the slicing operation does not need to allocate memory.

"Slicing operation" refers to things like `s1[x:y]` and not slice initialization or `make([]int, x)`. For example:

```
var s1 = []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} // <<- allocates (or put on stack)
s2 := s1[1:3]                    // <<- does not (normally) allocate
```

That is, the second line is *similar* to:

```
type SliceHeader struct {
        Data uintptr
        Len  int
        Cap  int
}
…
example := SliceHeader{&s1[1], 2, 5}
```

Usually local variables like `example` get put onto the stack. It's just like if this was done instead of using a struct:

```
var exampleData            uintptr
var exampleLen, exampleCap int
```

Those `example*` variables go onto the stack.
Only if the code does `return &example` or `otherFunc(&example)` or otherwise allows a pointer to this to escape will the compiler be forced to allocate the struct (or slice header) on the heap.

> Then it mentions that it was originally a pointer to that slice structure, and it needed to allocate memory for a new object. Why does it not need to do that now?

Imagine that instead of the above you did:

```
example2 := &SliceHeader{…same…}
// or
example3 := new(SliceHeader)
example3.Data = …
example3.Len = …
example3.Cap = …
```

i.e. the type is `*SliceHeader` rather than `SliceHeader`.
This is effectively what slices used to be (pre Go 1.0) according to what you mention.

It also used to be that both `example2` and `example3` would have to be allocated on the heap. That is the "memory for a new object" being refered to. I *think* that now escape analysis will try and put both of these onto the stack as long as the pointer(s) are kept local to the function so it's not as big of an issue anymore. Either way though, avoiding one level of indirection is good, it's almost always faster to copy three ints compared to copying a pointer and dereferencing it repeatedly.

Comment: Why would it be on the heap before though? Example 2 and 3. Why? Otherwise thanks :D

Comment: Never mind got it, it's because go returned the address of the new structure right, and as you said return &example puts it on the heap

Comment: @aubble correct. I wasn't as clear as I could have been. `var x int` never needs to be on the heap since it can't be referenced past the lifetime of the function. As soon as you do `&x` or `y := new(int)` they *might* live past the life of the function (referred to as escaping) and if so they need to be on the heap. (The stack space goes away "automatically" and cheaply on function return).

Comment: one more thing. " Even with a fast allocator, that creates a lot of unnecessary work for the garbage collector, and we found that, as was the case with strings above, programs avoided slicing operations in favor of passing explicit indices. " Where do the strings above have this? (should I make a new question or add this into my original question(

Comment: Would the array itself be on the heap as well because of the pointer returned in the structure?

Comment: @aubble I believe in the past pretty much everything created with `make` got put on the stack so `slice := make([]int, x)` would have the slice header (ptr, len, cap) on the stack but the underlying array on the heap. At some point however escape analysis improved such that it's less clear now. Take some smallish program/packages and compile with `go build -gcflags="-m"` to see what escapes and what doesn't. You'll find many small/medium slices don't escape and are put on the stack. But add `&x` or do `fmt.Print(&x)` and you'll see it does escape and gets moved to the heap.

Comment: @dave But one point that is mentioned is that even  "the slicing operation does not need to allocate memory, not even for the slice header".Not sure but whenever you create new slice ,atleast header shud be created as this slice starts at some index than the one it is created from ?

Answer (score 2):

Every data type allocates memory when it's initialized. In blog, he clearly mention

> the slicing operation does not need to allocate memory.

And he is right. Now see, [how slice works in golang](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices).

> Slices hold references to an underlying array, and if you assign one
>   slice to another, both refer to the same array. If a function takes a
>   slice argument, changes it makes to the elements of the slice will be
>   visible to the caller, analogous to passing a pointer to the
>   underlying array.

Comment: I don't disagree with this, just the last part about how it doesn't need to allocate because its a multiword structure. But it says a pointer would, thats what I'm confused on. Third paragraph of the slices stuff.